# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' however google-services already exist

Tags: android, firebase

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
}
```

i have an error while synchronize project with firebase, but i already have google-services.json on root app folder.

how to fixed it ? thanks

Comment: show me your google-service.json path

Comment: Do post the complete error logs and complete gradle files if possible.